# Blazor authentication role based

Tags: authentication, blazor, roles

I'm working on a client-side blazor application with the last webassembly version (3.2.0).

I started the project from the visual tool with enabling local authentications and I tried to add roles.

First, I added the roles in the ApplicationDbContext :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
               .HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "User", NormalizedName = "USER", Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
               .HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN", Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
    }
}
```

Then I added Roles to the IdentityBuilder in the startup class :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
       .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

   services.AddIdentityServer()
       .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

   services.AddAuthentication()
       .AddIdentityServerJwt();

   services.AddControllersWithViews();
   services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

And then in my DbInitializer I created an Admin account with both roles :

```
    private async Task SeedASPIdentityCoreAsync()
    {
        if (!await context.Users.AnyAsync())
        {
            var admin = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "admin@admin.com",
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(admin, "aA&123");
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new Exception(result.Errors.First().Description);
            }

            result = await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(admin, new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "admin@admin.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "admin@admin.com")
                });


            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("admin@admin.com");

            try
            {
                result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
                result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            }
            catch
            {
                await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
                throw;
            }

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
                throw new Exception(result.Errors.First().Description);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the roles doen't appear in the JWT, and the client-side has no idea about the roles.

How can I add the roles in the JWT, as with the new version of blazor, there is no need of the LoginController ? (If i well understood the changes)

Comment: You can add the roles to the AuthenticationStateProvider in the client app.  See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authenticationstateprovider-service  If this cannot be useful to you, let me know, and I'll show you how to do that in Asp.Net Core

Comment: @enet Yeah I used a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider in an other app, and write the ParseClaimsFromJwt method, but with the new version, I don't know where to tell the server to add the role claim inside the token

Comment: " I don't know where to tell the server to add the role claim inside the token " You don't tell the server. You do that on the client. You inject the AuthenticationStateProvider into a component, perhaps the App component, gets the AuthenticationState object, and add to it the role claims..... "add the role claim inside the token" You don't add the role claims inside the token. You add the role claims into the AuthenticationState object.

Comment: Ok so I have to create a UserController, and in the GetAuthenticationStateAsync() method, I call this UserController which send me back a user item, containing the roles, and I create the AuthenticationState object, filled with the role as claim ?

Because in my previous project, I had a LoginController, which filled the token with the roles, and the AuthenticationStateProvider deserilized the roles frome the token. But as the new version support OIDC, I thought this could be donne automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found what I needed :

1) Create a CustomUserFactory in your client App

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.Internal;

public class CustomUserFactory
    : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>
{
    public CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor)
    {
    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
        RemoteUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
            var roleClaims = identity.FindAll(identity.RoleClaimType);

            if (roleClaims != null && roleClaims.Any())
            {
                foreach (var existingClaim in roleClaims)
                {
                    identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);
                }

                var rolesElem = account.AdditionalProperties[identity.RoleClaimType];

                if (rolesElem is JsonElement roles)
                {
                    if (roles.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                    {
                        foreach (var role in roles.EnumerateArray())
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(options.RoleClaim, role.GetString()));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(options.RoleClaim, roles.GetString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

2) Register the client factory

```
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization()
.AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();
```

3) In the Server App, call IdentityBuilder.AddRoles

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

4) Configure Identity Server

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
});


JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

There is an other way, by creating a ProfileService

5) User Authorization mechanisms :

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">
```

Source : https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server.md#Name-and-role-claim-with-API-authorization