# Blazor Server Role based authorization in Windows AD

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, blazor

Since days I try to get authorization working for my Blazor site based on AD group memebership but I cannot make it work.

I am using .NET Core 6 on IIS (IIS Express for testing) in an Windows Domain. I am logged in as AD user and authentication works, so my Blazor page is able to identfy myself.

Now I want to restrict access to some controllers or APIs to specified AD groups and
finally I found a policy option

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy ( "MyRole",  policy => policy.RequireRole(@"Domain\Group"));
});
```

To check if the authorization is working I tried

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="MyRole">
    <p>You are in MyRole</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

and I also tried

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyRole")]
public class MyWebAPIController: ControllerBase
{
...
}
```

Both tells me that I am not authorized altough I am a member of the specified AD group

This is my startup script:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy ( "MyRole",  policy => policy.RequireRole(@"Domain\Group"));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");  

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllers(); //<======= this is the line you need to add 
  endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
});


app.Run();
```

Can anyone tell me if there is something missing or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks !!

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306681/blazor-authentication-role-based) about using role based authorization in Blazor.

Comment: The demo is for client side Blazor

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Not really. I finally modified the tutorial given here by try and error: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0)